# Getting unassigned phone numbers for Skype for Business in powershell

Tags: powershell, lync

Has anyone ever done something like this in powershell? I'm automating new user creation and have to set up their skype for business accounts. Here's what I have so far:

```
<# set up skype for business #>
Enable-CsUser -Identity $FULLNAME `
 -RegistrarPool REDACTED
 -SipAddress $SIP
Set-CsUser $FULLNAME `
 -EnterpriseVoiceEnabled $true `
 -ExchangeArchivingPolicy Uninitialized `
 -LineURI $PHONENUMBER
# only for driver manager/managers
Grant-CsConferencingPolicy $FULLNAME `
 -PolicyName $ConferencingPolicy
Grant-CsExternalAccessPolicy -identity $FULLNAME `
 -PolicyName 'Allow external access'
```

All I have left is the to assign the LineURI, and I can't seem to find anything about how to do that. I did, however, find a [script](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Find-next-available-number-58391c72) that does this, but it doesn't seem like it's specific to my needs. My question is this: how can I query Skype for Business in powershell to grab the first unassigned number and assign it as the LineURI? I have been using New-CSUnassignedNumber but cannot seem to make any headway.

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart Can't believe I forgot to put that in. Edited with the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SfB doesn't keep a record of your number ranges, so it doesn't know if you assigning 1299 is the last in a range, or if the range stretches into the 1300's

```
Get-CsUser | ? LineUri | Select LineUri | Sort
```

this will give you a sorted list of all assigned uri's in your organization, so you'll be able to pick out ones which may be assignable, regardless you can use a number of methods to find what you're looking for, but you may be interested in this for the longer-term approach, it's a script which takes in your number ranges, and outputs a list of the used and available ones in a nice Csv.

```
#region Input
$NumRangeKeyTable = @{
    #Make sure numbers are in the same format as they are in Skype,
    #Do not include any ';ext' or 'tel:' etc. formatting!
    #Put single numbers in the format:
    #    "+35313456789" = ""
    #Put number ranges in the format:
    #    "+35313456700" = "+35313456799"

    "+35313456789" = ""
    "+35313456700" = "+35313456799"
}

#Save Location, set to $null to be prompted for location.
$FileName = $null 
#endregion

#region Code
#region Helper Functions
Function Get-CsAssignedURIs {
$AllNumbers = @()
$Users = Get-CsUser
$Users | ? {$_.LineURI -ne ""} | %{ $AllNumbers += New-Object PSObject -Property @{Name = $_.DisplayName ; SipAddress = $_.SipAddress ; Number = $_.LineURI ; Type = "User" }}
$Users | ? {$_.PrivateLine -ne ""} | %{ $AllNumbers += New-Object PSObject -Property @{Name = $_.DisplayName ; SipAddress = $_.SipAddress ; Number = $_.PrivateLine ; Type = "PrivateLine" }}
Get-CsRgsWorkflow | Where-Object {$_.LineURI -ne ""} | Select Name,LineURI | %{$AllNumbers += New-Object PSObject -Property @{Name = $_.Name ; SipAddress = $_.PrimaryUri ; Number = $_.LineURI ; Type = "Workflow" }}
Get-CsCommonAreaPhone -Filter {LineURI -ne $null} | %{ $AllNumbers += New-Object PSObject -Property @{Name = $_.DisplayName ; SipAddress = $_.SipAddress ; Number = $_.LineURI ; Type = "CommonArea" }}
Get-CsAnalogDevice -Filter {LineURI -ne $null} | %{ $AllNumbers += New-Object PSObject -Property @{Name = $_.DisplayName ; SipAddress = $_.SipAddress ; Number = $_.LineURI ; Type = "AnalogDevice" }}
Get-CsExUmContact -Filter {LineURI -ne $null} | %{ $AllNumbers += New-Object PSObject -Property @{Name = $_.DisplayName ; SipAddress = $_.SipAddress ; Number = $_.LineURI ; Type = "ExUmContact" }}
Get-CsDialInConferencingAccessNumber -Filter {LineURI -ne $null} | %{ $AllNumbers += New-Object PSObject -Property @{Name = $_.DisplayName ; SipAddress = $_.PrimaryUri ; Number = $_.LineURI ; Type = "DialInAccess" }}
Get-CsTrustedApplicationEndpoint -Filter {LineURI -ne $null} | %{ $AllNumbers += New-Object PSObject -Property @{Name = $_.DisplayName ; SipAddress = $_.SipAddress ; Number = $_.LineURI ; Type = "ApplicationEndpoint" }}
Return $AllNumbers
}

function Get-UniqueExt {
    Param(
        [string]$Uri1,
        [string]$Uri2
    )

    $Reg = "^([0-9+])+$"

    if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($uri1) -and [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($Uri2)) { return "Two blank strings provided" }
    if ($Uri1 -eq $Uri2) { return $Uri1 }
    if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($uri1)) { return $Uri2 }
    if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($uri2)) { return $Uri1 }
    if ($Uri1.Length -ne $Uri2.Length) { return "Strings cannot be different lengths" }
    if (($Uri1 -notmatch $Reg) -or ($Uri2 -notmatch $Reg)) { return "Strings must be in the format '0123..' or '+123..'" }

    ($Uri1.Length-1)..0 | % {
        if ($Uri1[$_] -ne $Uri2[$_]) { $Diff = $_ }
    }

    $Start = $Uri1.Substring(0,$Diff)
    $Sub1 = $Uri2.Substring($Diff)
    $Sub2 = $Uri1.Substring($Diff)

    if ($Sub1 -lt $Sub2) {
        $Min = $Sub1 ; $Max = $Sub2
    } else {
        $Min = $Sub2 ; $Max = $Sub1
    }

    $FormatStr = "" ; 1..$Min.Length | % { $FormatStr += "0"}
    $Min..$Max | % { "$($Start)$($_.ToString($FormatStr))" }
}

function Save-ToFile {
    Param(
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$True)]
    $Item = $null,
    [switch]$ReturnName,
    $ExtFilter = "*",
    $WinTitle = "Select File",
    $FileTypeDisplay = $null
    )

    If ($FileTypeDisplay -eq $null) {
    If ($ExtFilter -eq "*") {
        $ExtName = "All"
    } Else {
        $ExtName = (Get-Culture).TextInfo.ToTitleCase($ExtFilter)
    }} Else {
        $ExtName = (Get-Culture).TextInfo.ToTitleCase($FileTypeDisplay) }

    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms") | Out-Null
    $FolderDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog
    $FolderDialog.Filter = "$($ExtName) files (*.$($ExtFilter.ToLowerInvariant()))| *.$($ExtFilter.ToLowerInvariant())"
    $FolderDialog.Title = $WinTitle
    $Result = $FolderDialog.ShowDialog()

    If ($Result -eq "OK"){
    $Item | Out-File $FolderDialog.FileName -Append
    If ($ReturnName) { return $FolderDialog.FileName }}
    Else {
    Write-Error "No file selected" }
}
#endregion

Function Main {
Param ( [Hashtable]$NumRanges )

#region Process Data
$AllNums = $NumRanges.Keys | % {
    Get-UniqueExt -Uri1 $_ -Uri2 $NumRanges[$_]
}
$S4BNums = Get-CsAssignedURIs
$S4BNums | % { $_.Number = ($_.Number.Split(';')[0] -ireplace "tel:","") }

$KT = @{}

$S4BNums | % {
    $KT[$_.Number] = $_
}

$FullRecord = $AllNums | Sort | % {
    $Number = $_
    $Type = ""
    $Name = ""

    if ($KT[$_] -ne $null){
        $UseDetails = $KT[$_]
        $Name = $UseDetails.Name
        $Type = $UseDetails.Type
    }

    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Number = $Number
        Name = $Name
        Type = $Type
    }
}
#endregion

return $FullRecord
}

$Results = Main $NumRangeKeyTable

#region Output-Data
    if ($FileName -eq $null) {
    $FileName = (Save-ToFile -Item "" -ReturnName -ExtFilter "Csv")
    }
    if ($FileName -ne $null) {
    $Results | Export-Csv -Path $FileName -NoTypeInformation
    } else { $Results | Out-GridView }
#endregion
#endregion
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Matt no worries, I ran into basically the exact same problem for our own SfB environment and wanted something I can reuse on customer sites too.